# SQL Query to select row when list of five values get match with any of five coloumn

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sugarcrm

I have a table name called Kits in which 5 column is there for Book ISBN .

- So i want to select Row when 5 different value  of ISBN gets matched
  with any of the 5
  coloumn(ISBN_BOOK1,ISBN_BOOK2,ISBN_BOOK3,ISBN_BOOK4,ISBN_BOOK5) of
  table kits meant for Storing ISBN.
- if any one of the ISBN not exist then return NULL.

I have written sql query for this but i am getting row output even if there is matching any single value or multiple value but it should give out put when all value match.
Here is my sql query:

```
Select * 
  from kits k
  left 
  join kits_cstm kc
    on k.id = kc.id_c 
 where '8192933563' 
   and '8192933567' 
   and '8192933568' 
   and '8192933564' 
   and '7589765432' IN (kc.isbn_book_1_c,kc.isbn_book_2_c,kc.isbn_book_3_c,kc.isbn_book_4_c,kc.isbn_book_5_c) 
   and kc.city_c = 'BAN' 
   and kc.kit_for_c = 'SCHL' 
   and k.deleted = 0 
 ORDER 
    BY k.kit_id DESC
```

Comment: So all 5 have to match but in any order?

Comment: Oh boy. Where to begin. Well, let's begin within normalisation. Solve that, and all your problems will miraculously disappear.

Comment: Move the kc conditions from WHERE to ON, to get a real left join. Like this it executes as a regular inner join!

Comment: @jarlh Yes, but I think the problems with this query are larger than that!

Comment: @Strawberry, oops, I didn't mean that my comment was the whole solution, just a part of it. Or rather a small outer join programming lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your where condition like this:

```
WHERE 
(kc.isbn_book_1_c IN ('8192933563', '8192933567', '8192933568', '8192933564', '7589765432') AND
kc.isbn_book_2_c IN ('8192933563', '8192933567', '8192933568', '8192933564', '7589765432') AND
kc.isbn_book_3_c IN ('8192933563', '8192933567', '8192933568', '8192933564', '7589765432') AND
kc.isbn_book_4_c IN ('8192933563', '8192933567', '8192933568', '8192933564', '7589765432') AND
kc.isbn_book_5_c IN ('8192933563', '8192933567', '8192933568', '8192933564', '7589765432') )
AND ( kc.isbn_book_1_c != kc.isbn_book_2_c != kc.isbn_book_3_c != kc.isbn_book_4_c != kc.isbn_book_5_c ) 
AND sam_kits_cstm.city_c='BAN' 
AND sam_kits_cstm.kit_for_c='SCHL'
AND sam_kits.deleted=0
```

Comment: Hi Arth thanks for reply but this where condition also  giving same output as i was getting previously.

Comment: Did I understand your need ? Here, all of the 5 cols need to contain one of the 5 values... Do you need another rule ?

Comment: yes you got it clear all the 5 col should have any one of the 5 value

Comment: Would you need all the cols values to be different ?

Comment: Yes all the cols value to be different- @JBA

Comment: So add one more condition :). Like this : and ( sam_kits_cstm.isbn_book_1_c != sam_kits_cstm.isbn_book_2_c !=sam_kits_cstm.isbn_book_3_c !=sam_kits_cstm.isbn_book_4_c !=sam_kits_cstm.isbn_book_5_c ) and you should be fine

Comment: still getting same result it giving row which matched even two value '8192933563' & '7589765432'

Comment: that is quite weird, could you give as sample, the col values of the row that is returned when you only match 2 values ?

Comment: I changed the query table name (you might have edited it in the meantime ?) to match your alias 'kc'

Comment: It cannot be constructive to pursue this solution, but hey, whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @JBA unfortunately in stored database two isbn value were same .So after changing those value i got what i was looking for